# difference between EJBHome, EJBObject & EJBLocalHome, EJBLocalObject

Tags: ejb

Am new to EJB technology. I would like to know about basic EJB terms,

EJBHome, EJBObject & EJBLocalHome, EJBLocalObject

and what is the difference between EJBLocalHome and EJBHome also EJBLocalObject and EJBObject

pls provide me solutions

thanks

Comment: I believe those terms are only applicable **before** EJB 3. You should probably avoid EJB 2.* if at all possible.

Comment: No but my project is on EJB :(  can any one suggest some good tutorial/videos on EJB 2.x

Comment: [google](http://google.com) is a useful site that could help you find a tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

[Different beans definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97688_16/toplink.903/b10065/intro.htm)<- Here you can refer the definitions. The main difference is that EJBLocalObject and EJBLocalHome can only be accessed from within the same server on which the beans are deployed. Though EJBLocalHome is accessible via JNDI, still same server constraint is enforced.

**The EJBHome** -> An instance of a class that implements the home interface supplied by the bean developer. This instance is accessible from JNDI and provides ***all create and finder methods for the EJB***. The EJBHome does not have persistent state.

**The EJBObject** -> An instance of a generated class that implements the ***remote interface*** defined by the bean developer. This instance wraps the bean and ***all client interaction is made through this object***. The EJBObject does not have persistent state.